# hg verify doesn't return 0 or 1

Tags: python, mercurial, popen

According to the help

```
$ hg -v help verify
hg verify

verify the integrity of the repository

    Verify the integrity of the current repository.

    This will perform an extensive check of the repository's integrity,
    validating the hashes and checksums of each entry in the changelog,
    manifest, and tracked files, as well as the integrity of their crosslinks
    and indices.

    Returns 0 on success, 1 if errors are encountered.
```

Output from console

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> p = Popen(['hg', 'verify', '-R', 'sample-master'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> out
'checking changesets\nchecking manifests\ncrosschecking files in changesets and manifests\nchecking files\n2186 files, 214 changesets, 3055 total revisions\n'
>>> err
>>> """-q is quite suppress output"""
>>> p = Popen(['hg', 'verify', '-R', 'sample-master', '-q'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> out
''
```

I now corrupted the `.hg/store`

```
>>> out, err = Popen(['hg', 'verify', '-R', 'sample-master', '-q'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
>>> out, err
('', ' data/req.txt.i@119: missing revlog!\n 119: empty or missing req.txt\n req.txt@119: 8befed264a2f in manifests not found\n3 integrity errors encountered!\n(first damaged changeset appears to be 119)\n')
```

I don't see 0 or 1. Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [process return code](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode):

```
p = Popen(['hg', 'verify', '-R', 'natrium-master', '-q'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print p.returncode
```

The documentation is referring to the [exist status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of the process.

Comment: Ah. I never knew that. So used to reading the stdin and stdout. Confused. Now I learned something. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @CppLearner -- and if you ever want the process return code from the last executed program in a `sh` style shell, you can get it from `$?`

Comment: @mgilson Just supply `$?` to Popen?

Comment: @CppLearner: No, if you ran `hg verify` in a shell and wanted the return code, you'd use `$?`. In Python you use `returncode`. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters All right. I now understand. Thanks for educating me :)